# MySQL query performance with subselects - table with millions of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-performance

I know there have been a lot of questions about sql query performance improvement, but I was not able to use the answers of those questions to improve my queries performance (enough).

Since I wanted something more flexible than rsync & fslint, I've written a little java tool that walks file trees and stores paths & checksums in a mysql database.

You'll find my table structure here:
http://code.google.com/p/directory-scanner/source/browse/trunk/sql/create_table.sql - 
at first I only had one table, but then I thought I could save a lot of space if I move the redundant quite long strings of the directory paths into a seperate place and make it an 1:n relationship

I've defined those two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX files_sha1 ON files (sha1);
CREATE INDEX files_size ON files (size);
```

Now the queries that bug me are those:
http://code.google.com/p/directory-scanner/source/browse/trunk/sql/reporingQueries.sql

The worst of them is the last one, that should with a very high probability always return an empty set (sha1 collisions & mistakenly multiple inserted files):

```
SELECT 
    d.path, 
    d.id, 
    f.filename, 
    f.id, 
    f.size, 
    f.scandate, 
    f.sha1, 
    f.lastmodified 
FROM files f 
INNER JOIN directories d 
    ON d.id = f.dir_id 
WHERE EXISTS ( /* same sha1 but different size */ 
    SELECT ff.id 
    FROM files ff 
    WHERE ff.sha1 = f.sha1 
    AND ff.size <> f.size 
) 
OR EXISTS ( /* files with same name and path but different id */ 
    SELECT ff2.id 
    FROM files ff2 
    INNER JOIN directories dd2 
        ON dd2.id = ff2.dir_id 
    WHERE ff2.id <> f.id 
    AND ff2.filename = f.filename 
    AND dd2.path = d.path 
) 
ORDER BY f.sha1
```

It ran well enough within less than a second as long as I had only 20k rows (after creating my indexes), but now that I have 750k rows, it literary runs for hours, and mysql totaly uses up one of my cpu cores for the whole time.

EXPLAIN for this query gives this result:

```
id ; select_type ; table ; type ; possible_keys ; key ; key_len ; ref ; rows ; filtered ; Extra
1 ; PRIMARY ; d ; ALL ; PRIMARY ; NULL ; NULL ; NULL ; 56855 ; 100.0 ; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 ; PRIMARY ; f ; ref ; dir_id ; dir_id ; 4 ; files.d.id ; 13 ; 100.0 ; Using where
3 ; DEPENDENT SUBQUERY ; dd2 ; ALL ; PRIMARY ; NULL ; NULL ; NULL ; 56855 ; 100.0 ; Using where
3 ; DEPENDENT SUBQUERY ; ff2 ; ref ; dir_id ; dir_id ; 4 ; files.dd2.id ; 13 ; 100.0 ; Using where
2 ; DEPENDENT SUBQUERY ; ff ; ref ; files_sha1 ; files_sha1 ; 23 ; files.f.sha1 ; 1 ; 100.0 ; Using where
```

My other queries are also not quick with 750k rows, but finish at least within 15 minutes or something the like (however, I would like them to also work with millions of rows..)

UPDATE: Thanks radashk for the comment, but the indexes you suggested seem to be created automatically by mysql -->

```
"Table","Non_unique","Key_name","Seq_in_index","Column_name","Collation","Cardinality","Sub_part","Packed","Null","Index_type","Comment","Index_comment"
"files","0","PRIMARY","1","id","A","698397","NULL","NULL",,"BTREE",,
"files","1","dir_id","1","dir_id","A","53722","NULL","NULL",,"BTREE",,
"files","1","scanDir_id","1","scanDir_id","A","16","NULL","NULL","YES","BTREE",,
"files","1","files_sha1","1","sha1","A","698397","NULL","NULL","YES","BTREE",,
"files","1","files_size","1","size","A","174599","NULL","NULL",,"BTREE",,
```

UPDATE2: Thanks Eugen Rieck! I consider your answer a good replacement for this query, since it most likly will return an empty set anyway I will just select the data to display the user to describe the problem later in another query.
To make me really happy it would be great if someone could take a look at my other queries as well :D

UPDATE3: The answer from Justin Swanhart inspired me to the following solution: instead of having queries to check for directories and files that have been inserted multiple times unintentionally, just create unique constraints like this:

```
ALTER TABLE directories ADD CONSTRAINT uc_dir_path UNIQUE (path);
ALTER TABLE files ADD CONSTRAINT uc_files UNIQUE(dir_id, filename);
```

However, I wonder how much this would negatively effect the performance of insert statements, could somebody comment on this please?

UPDATE4:

```
ALTER TABLE directories ADD CONSTRAINT uc_dir_path UNIQUE (path);
```

doesn't work, since its to long..

```
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

UPDATE5:

Okey, this is the solution I'm gonna use for replacing the query I quoted above in my initial question:

For the first part, finding sha1 collisions, I will use this:

```
SELECT sha1
FROM files
GROUP BY sha1
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
AND MIN(size)<>MAX(size)
```

And if it returns anything, I will select the details with another query WHERE sha1 = ?

I guess this query will run best, with this index defined:

```
CREATE INDEX sha1_size ON files (sha1, size);
```

For verifying that no duplicated directories exist, I will use this, since he doesn't allow a constraint (see UPDATE4 above):

```
SELECT path
FROM directories
GROUP BY path
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

And for the duplicated files I will try to create this constraint:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX filename_dir ON files (filename, dir_id);
```

This runs quite fast (15 to 20 sec) and I don't need to create other indexes before it to make it faster. Also the error message contains the details I need to display the problem to the user (which is unlikely anyway since I check for those things before inserting)

Now there are only 5 more queries to make perform in less time ;) thanks for the great help so far Eugen & Justin!

UPDATE6: Okey, so since it's been a few days since the last response from anybody, I'm just gonna accept Justin's answer, since that was the one that helped me the most. I incorporated what I learned from both of you into my app and released version 0.0.4 here: http://code.google.com/p/directory-scanner/downloads/detail?name=directory-scanner-0.0.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: Index the id`s you connect the tables with! files.id, directories.id

Comment: I would put the unique index on (filename, dir_id).  You already have an index on (dir_id) for the FOREIGN KEY constraint, and you might want to look up entries by filename, which will not be possible if the index is (dir_id, filename)

Comment: ah, okey, now I understand what you meant. okey. However, after adding that constraint, he doesn't seem to want to let me remove it again --> `ALTER TABLE files DROP INDEX uc_files;
ERROR 1553 (HY000): Cannot drop index 'uc_files': needed in a foreign key constraint` --> probably he automatically removed the index on dir_id while creating this unique index..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't verify without building your tables an dpopulating, I'd try something like

```
-- This checks the SHA1 collisions
SELECT
  MIN(id) AS id,
FROM files
GROUP BY sha1
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
AND MIN(size)<>MAX(size)

-- This checks for directory duplicates
SELECT
  MIN(path) AS path
FROM directories
GROUP BY path
HAVING COUNT(*)>1

-- This checks for file duplicates
SELECT
  MIN(f.id) AS id
FROM files AS f
INNER JOIN files AS ff 
   ON f.dir_id=ff.dir_id
   AND f.filename=ff.filename
GROUP BY f.id
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Run one after the other.

**Edit**

3rd query was bogous - sorry for that

Comment: Or, union these together to get one list of problems (perhaps with an additional column specifying where the failure is).

Comment: My rationale for doing it 1-by-1 was e.g. if you have a directory duplicate, you need to fix it first, before file duplicates can be checked in a meaningfull way.

Comment: Thanks! thats a good idea! The last statement still takes 3 minutes to finish, but a lot better than a few hours ;) would you mind also taking a look at my other queries, or would it be better to create a new question for those?

Comment: You can spped up Query #3 by adding an index on files.filename - I suspect this to be significant, if there are many files/directory. I'll look at your other queries tomorrow - it's saturday midnight here.

Comment: The third query is better served by (filename, dir_id).  The whole thing will then be a loose index scan.  You can also remove MIN() from f.id.  You are grouping on f.id, so a MIN() on it is meaningless.  Same for query two.  If you really never ever want to query by filename, then drop the index on dir_id, and create a new unique one (dir_id, filename).  I suspect your application will need to query by filename occasionally though, such as for search.

Comment: Okey, I profiled my idea with the unique constraints and your statements.
your last statement with the files takes (2 min 48.08 sec)
ALTER TABLE files ADD CONSTRAINT uc_files UNIQUE(dir_id, filename);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (16.64 sec) --> is a lot quicker, and fails even faster on a prolbem, and gives all the neccesary info in the error description --> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2-MobileFrontend-master-12384ac.tar.gz' for key 'uc_files'
And before starting a directory scan I will just remove those unique constraints to allow for quicker insertions

Comment: Just saw your two comments, sorry for ignoring them at first;
Eugen: Thanks for promising to look at my other queries tomorrow, that would be great! (yes its nearly midnight here too, I'm also going to rush into bed now)
Justin: I do not plan to add a search by filename feature, for me its more about asking questions like finding duplicate files or checking if mirrors are in sync and stuff like that. the filename is just to display it to the user to understand what has been found.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subqueries try using a UNION and two well indexed queries with joins.

First you will need two indexes (based on the schema in the create_table.sql you provided):

```
ALTER TABLE files add key (sha1, size);
alter table files add key(filename, dir_id);
```

Then you will need to rewrite the query:

```
(SELECT 
    d.path, 
    d.id, 
    f.filename, 
    f.id, 
    f.size, 
    f.scandate, 
    f.sha1, 
    f.lastmodified 
FROM files f 
INNER JOIN directories d 
    ON d.id = f.dir_id 
INNER JOIN files files2
    USING(sha1)
WHERE files2.size != f.size)

UNION

(SELECT 
    d.path, 
    d.id, 
    f.filename, 
    f.id, 
    f.size, 
    f.scandate, 
    f.sha1, 
    f.lastmodified 
FROM files f 
INNER JOIN directories d 
    ON d.id = f.dir_id
INNER JOIN files files2
    ON files2.id != f.id
   AND files2.filename = f.filename
INNER JOIN directories d2
   ON files2.dir_id = d2.id
  AND d2.path = d.path)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! those alter talbe add key statements, what would this do exactly? would that add an unique constraint on sha1+size? I don't think that that would be a good idea, its more like there should be no different sizes for one sha1, but also this could theoretically happen, and should be insertable.

Comment: Indexes don't have to be UNIQUE.  By creating an index on the combination of (sha1,size) you allow the optimizer to do an index-only access on the file table for the self-join.  The second index allows an index-only access for the second query.  The filename part of the index is used for the join, and the dir_id is in the index already, so it is then used for the directory lookup without accessing the actual row (only the index).

Comment: Yep, I know they don't have to be unique, but a "key" has to be unique, doesn't it?! I never knew of this "add key" statement, I thought there can be only one primary key in every table, and foreign keys but those are a different matter. I would not have connected "key" with "index" in my head..

Comment: KEY and INDEX are synonymous in MySQL.  ALTER TABLE ADD KEY, ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX and CREATE INDEX all do the same thing.

Comment: oh... okey, thanks for the clarifications! I guess I would need to profile that, but I don't want to create to many indexes, because those would probably negatively effect insert & update performance..

Comment: Indexes are a tradeoff of space-for-time.  They use a little extra time (at insertion time) and space (in memory and on disk) to make big gains in query execution times.  Which is more important, slowing overall loading of a data set by a few seconds, or getting queries over millions of rows that run in seconds instead of hours?

Comment: yeah of course you're right. But since the creation of indexes seems to only take half a minute, I'm thinking of implementing a mode switch - removing all indexes for scanning and inserting new files, and adding them again before running reports. (Since in my application the most likely case is a single-user-database, where the user only does one of both at a time)

Answer (score 0):

Do you take a kind of cross join in your second subquery. Try to change second subquery to:

```
SELECT ff2.id 
FROM files ff2 
WHERE ff2.id <> f.id 
AND ff2.dir_id  = d.dir_id 
AND ff2.filename = f.filename
```

and create an index over `dir_id, filename` on `files` table.

Comment: well I did that on purpose, since it would also be possible (and likely) that both the directory and the file is inserted twice, then the dir_id would not be the same, only the directory.path would be the same, therefore the extra join. I think splitting the questions in 3 statements like Eugen Rieck suggested and only ask if there are duplicate files after having established that there are no duplicate directories.